# Color propriety doesn't apply in icon, React-Js

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I install the react-icons lib and i changed the icon size but the color does't apply.

Code:

```
<TbCircleCheckFilled size={24} color="red" />
```

I want to change the color for my react-icon

Answer (score 0):

```
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";

<IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "blue", className: "global-class-name" }}>
  <div>
    <FaFolder />
  </div>
</IconContext.Provider>;
```

You can check the doc [here](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You must send the hexagecimal color, so it would be red

```
<TbCircleCheckFilled size={24} color="#FF0000" />
```